# How to set text in a QLabel and display '<>' characters?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qlabel, pyside2

Using PySide2 (basically PyQt5), I'm trying to `setText` in a QLabel that has the characters '<' and '>' in the string.  But, since these characters are used to modify the font, anything within those two characters disappears.  I tried escaping them with a backslash, but it still doesn't seem to work...

How can I get the '<' and '>' characters to show up in the QLabel?

EDIT: here's a bit what my code is doing (just snagged the important parts):

```
# color and text get set at various places in my code (len_infs is just the length of the
#    influence item list - hopefully that's obvious...)
#
color = '#FF0000'
text = 'Influence count &lt%d&gt exceeds minimum row count...' %len_infs

# status_label is a QLabel that displays the text in the appropriate color within the label
#
status_label.setText('status: <font color=%s>%s</font>' %(color, text))
```

As you can see, I'm using `&lt` and `&gt` in the string based on ekhumoro's suggestion, but I do not get '<' or '>' in the resulting QLabel text

I want it to print `status: Influence count <7> exceeds minimum row count...`

but it actually prints `status: Influence count &lt7&gt exceeds minimum row count...`

In both, 'status:' is white, while the rest is red as intended.

NOTE: Using `'<%d>'` in the string results in `status: Influence count  exceeds minimum row count...`

What else do I need to do to format the string properly?

Comment: Mind updating your question with `semicolons`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QLabel` class automatically supports [rich-text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), so you need to use [character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to escape special characters. For `<`, use `&lt;` and for `>`, use `&gt;`. If you can't edit the text directly, use [html.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) to do the conversion.

Alternatively, to turn off rich-text support altogether, you can do this:

```
label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
```

Comment: well, that didn't seem to work... I've updated my question with a bit more example to see if that can lead to a better solution...

Comment: @silent_sight. You need to use the **exact** text as I have shown it - `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Do not leave off the semi-colons.

Comment: oh, wow... somehow I didn't even see the semi-colons until you explicitly mentioned it...  And, yes, it works perfectly when you type it in right!